# How can I install graphite on solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, graphite

I've tried to follow the steps [mentioned here](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) with the pip installation and I can't figure out what services need to be started and how do I configure them. Is there a more clear guide somewhere or an installation script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I eventually and fortunately found a script someone made [here](https://github.com/maduma/graphite).